# Convert JSON string to plain key value pair for logging

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON string, where consist of structure something like below, basically I have a chain of VO's and each VO will have list of VO's and Map of VO's as well.

### sample:

```
"MessageHeader": {
    "type": "new",
    "id": 10,
    "add_record": "true",
},
"MessageBody": {
    "dob_required": false,
    "dept_name": "Purchase",
    "group": {
        "main_group": "main group",
        "sub_group": "sub group"
    },
    "family_info": {
        "person1": {
            "name": "HisName",
            "gender": "male",
            "age": "31",
            "office_info_present": {
                "office_name": "present office",
                "office_address": "some address"
                "some_other_vo":{

                },
            },
            "office_info_previous": {
                "office_name": "old office",
                "office_address": "some address"
            },            
        },
        "person2": {
            "name": "HerName",
            "gender": "Female",
            "age": "25",
        }
    },
    "active":true
}
```

I want to print each and every attribute name and its value in key value pair. I don't want to print the VO name, rather just the end attributes (leaf level attributes)

### like below string:

type=new id=10 add_record=true dob_required=false dept_name=purchase main_group="main group" sub_group="sub group" name=HisName gender=male age=31 .... name=HerName gender=Female age=25

How this can be done? I would prefer if it can be done using jackson. Otherwise also fine.

Comment: do you want to parse it ?

Comment: You can try with JSON to Plain Key Value Parsing:

https://github.com/tangkhaiphuong/jsonkv

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably by using Jackson's Tree Model, traversing it. Something like:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readValueAsTree(jsonInput);
Map<String,String> flat = new HashMap<String,String>();
traverse(root, flat);

public void traverse(JsonNode node, Map<String,String> result)
{
   Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> it = node.fields();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> entry = it.next();
     JsonNode n = entry.getValue();
     if (n.isObject()) { // if JSON object, traverse recursively
       traverse(n);
     } else { // if not, just add as String
       result.put(entry.getKey(), n.asText());
     }
   } 
}
```

and you'll get a Map that you can print.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [this link](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) for creating POGO class for your response. It will automatically generate class for your response.

Use  [google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list)  library to parse your response.

Comment: I dont want to create a pogo, I just need to parse and print each and every attribute. Is it possible to parse using jackson?

Answer (score 0):

Yes jackson can be used to parse. but its not straight forward.
There are few implementations similar to JAXB for XML. But I never tested them
Here is the rough code snippet.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\sample.json"));

        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
        long age = (Long) jsonObject.get("age");
        JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("messages");
        System.out.println("Name:"+name);
        System.out.println("Age:"+age);
        System.out.println("Messages:");
        Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```